# Which is the door to heaven

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

After living a peaceful and calm life, you die a painless death. Your spirit starts ascending into heaven when suddenly you are approaching two doors.

Both doors are completely identical and there is no way of telling them apart.
One door leads to heaven while the other descends to hell.

In front of each door are twin brothers, both identical. One of them always speaks the truth while the other one always lies.

You are to choose one brother at random and ask one question to him.

**What will you ask him so that you can find the right door ?**

Answer (score 3):

> "What would the other guard say if I asked him which door leads to hell?"

If you ask the truth-teller, he'll point to the door to heaven (since the liar would lie).
If you ask the liar, he'll also point to the door to heaven (since he's lying about what the truth-teller would say).

So whichever door the guard points to, you should go through that door.